# Conditional inner join

Tags: mysql, join

I need to get allowed itemTypes for a user based on 2 different tables in a conditional way. If the users userGroup has any entries in the `userGroupItemTypes` table it should only show items that are in common between `userGroupItemTypes` AND `clientItemTypes` but if no entries exist in `userGroupItemTypes` for that users userGroup, then it should just get all the ones from `clientItemTypes`

itemTypes

```
itID    itemType
1       Item 1
2       Item 2
3       Item 3
```

clients

```
cID     client
1       Client 1
```

userGroups

```
ugID    userGroup
1       Group 1
2       Group 2
```

users

```
uID     user     cID     ugID
1       Fred     1       1
2       Sam      1       2
```

clientItemTypes

```
cID     itID
1       1
1       2
1       3
```

userGroupItemTypes

```
ugID    itID
2       1
2       2
```

Resaults should be:

```
uID     itID     user     itemType
1       1        Fred     Item 1
1       2        Fred     Item 2
2       1        Sam      Item 1
2       2        Sam      Item 2
2       3        Sam      Item 3
```

Basically i think the query should function like follows:

```
SELECT u.uID, it.itID, u.user, it.itemType
FROM users u
INNER JOIN clientItemTypes cit ON cit.cID = u.CID
INNER JOIN itemTypes it ON it.itID = cit.itID
IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userGroupItemTypes GROUP BY uID) > 0, INNER JOIN userGroupItemTypes ugit ON ugit.ugID = u.ugID, DO NOTHING)
```

But I do not know how to actually achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:
Here is a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=da55ee99562152ecd078e29109f33129)

Comment: Create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 or similar with the tables and sample data

Comment: @Lennart Added a dbfiddle with the tables and sample data in this post.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but you may consider splitting your query in 2 cases and the combine them with UNION

Comment: @Lennart Basically If a user's usergroup has no itemTypes assigned, it should fall back to the clients usergroups, but if it does have any assigned, it should only show the ones for the usergroup (as long as they are also in the clients itemTypes, so if an item type is removed from a client, no user can see it.)

Comment: These are the two cases I'm refering to. See if you can get case 1 right, then 2 and combine the two queries with union. I will see if i get time later today, but I think you should try this approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Lennarts suggestion I have used a UNION to get the results I need:

```
SELECT u.uID, it.itID, u.user, it.itemType
FROM users u
INNER JOIN clientItemTypes cit ON cit.cID = u.CID
INNER JOIN userGroupItemTypes ugit ON ugit.ugID = u.ugID
INNER JOIN itemTypes it ON it.itID = ugit.itID
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(ugit.ugID) AS total, uID FROM users u LEFT JOIN userGroupItemTypes ugit ON u.ugID = ugit.ugID GROUP BY uID) c ON c.uID = u.uID
WHERE c.total > 0
GROUP BY uID, itID
UNION
SELECT u.uID, it.itID, u.user, it.itemType
FROM users u
INNER JOIN clientItemTypes cit ON cit.cID = u.CID
INNER JOIN itemTypes it ON it.itID = cit.itID
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(ugit.ugID) AS total, uID FROM users u LEFT JOIN userGroupItemTypes ugit ON u.ugID = ugit.ugID GROUP BY uID) c ON c.uID = u.uID
WHERE c.total = 0
GROUP BY uID, itID
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=248f0d25b8000aea7de41afc8a8d3698)

Basically running the same queries twice, one requiring a userGroup to have itemTypes, the other requiring the userGroup NOT to have itemTypes, then using the union to combine the results.

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing it but it will have to do unless I can find another way of doing it.

---

Alternative Solution (thanks to Lennart):

Using `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT u.uID, it.itID, u.user, it.itemType
FROM users u
INNER JOIN clientItemTypes cit ON cit.cID = u.CID
INNER JOIN userGroupItemTypes ugit ON ugit.ugID = u.ugID
INNER JOIN itemTypes it ON it.itID = ugit.itID
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM userGroupItemTypes ugit
    WHERE u.ugID = ugit.ugID
)
GROUP BY uID, itID
UNION
SELECT u.uID, it.itID, u.user, it.itemType
FROM users u
INNER JOIN clientItemTypes cit ON cit.cID = u.CID
INNER JOIN itemTypes it ON it.itID = cit.itID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM userGroupItemTypes ugit
    WHERE u.ugID = ugit.ugID
)
GROUP BY uID, itID
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd681111998346e81419224acb82fd81)

Comment: Some suggestions. Use EXISTS and NOT EXISTS instead of the join's against the derived tables. Then you don't have to join in users once again, instead reference users from the outer select

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd681111998346e81419224acb82fd81 for an example

Comment: @lennart that helps a lot. Had no idea 'exists' and 'not exists' existed (self taught, still learning) if you wanted to make that into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Add it to your answer as an alternative solution. You can accept that in 2 days I think

Comment: @lennnart Will do later. Thanks again.